# rails nested model navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app with three models:

Client

```
has_many :papers
```

Paper

```
has_many :pages
belongs_to :client
```

Page

```
belongs_to :paper
```

I can do this in code: `@paper.client.name`

But I am unable to do `@paper.page.name` NoMethodError is produced

What I am doing wrong? These are all nested models, where Client is at high level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Paper` object has many pages, so there's no `page` method. If you want to get the names of all the pages belonging to a `Paper` object, you'll need to iterate over the `pages` association:

```
for page in @paper.pages
    puts page.name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

While Marc's explanation is absolutely correct, using a `for` loop in Ruby for this purpose (and just about *any* purpose really) is in not at all idiomatic. The usage of [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each) is far more common:

```
@paper.pages.each { |page| puts page.name }
```

If you just want the list of names, you can use [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map):

```
@paper.pages.map(&:name)
```

`map` will execute a block for each item in the collection and return an array of the results. The `&:name` is a shorthand for:

```
@paper.pages.map { |page| page.name }
```

[`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) plays a big part in idiomatic Ruby.

And, not to be **too** confusing, there's also [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) in Rails for just getting an array of a single attribute, but you should only use it if it's the only thing you want from the collection:

```
@paper.pages.pluck(:name)
```